# Pyside2 signal slots 2d array signature definition, equivalent for list of list

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

I am trying to connect a `signal` that emits a 2D array to a `slot` that processes that list of list.

I am using `@Slot(list)` in my `slot` definition and `SIGNAL("slot_method(QList<QList<QString>>)")` but that doesn't seem to work.

I would like to know what is proper conversion of a list of lists in `Qt` terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python there are no 2D lists, there are only lists so you must use the signature `list`.

Example:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore


class Sender(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = QtCore.Signal(list)

    def on_test(self):
        l = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["A", "B", "C", "D"]]
        self.signal.emit(l)


class Receiver(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.Slot(list)
    def on_receiver(self, l):
        print(l)
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    sender = Sender()
    receiver = Receiver()
    sender.signal.connect(receiver.on_receiver)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, sender.on_test)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: this worked fine, thanks. I guess using the `sender.signal.connect()` takes care of the signatures.

Comment: @bardao that's the new syntax, do not use the old connection.

Comment: does adding `Qt.AutoConnection` at the end provide any optimization for inter-threads connections?

Comment: @bardao Qt::AutoConnection allows Qt to choose to use Qt::DirectConnection if the receiver lives in the same slot of the sender or use Qt::QQueueConnection if it lives in another thread. If you know that you live in another thread use Qt::QQueueConnection, it is more readable: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum